# Creating number of specific jobs in pipeline dynamically

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am searching for an architectural solution for dynamically running an Azure pipeline. Let's assume that I will have a database containing information about various entities. Each entity holds essential information required to execute specific software. The number of entities will increase over time. Therefore, I would like to create a pipeline that reads data from the database (which is an easy step) and then generates an appropriate number of jobs based on that information. This is because each entity needs to run on a single VM. All the data is repeatable.

My initial idea was to create a new YAML template file and then override it in the first pipeline to trigger the appropriate actions. However, this approach seems somewhat inelegant, and I have concerns about its effectiveness.

Has anyone ever encountered a similar situation? Unfortunately, I am seeking a solution due to the limited number of pipelines that can be executed simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid we are not able to achieve your needs through single Pipeline.

The steps of obtaining the number of instances and setting the number of jobs in the Pipeline cannot be completed at the same time.

Based on your requirement, I suggest that you can use two pipelines to achieve this. One pipeline is used to get the number of the instances and pass the value to another pipeline via Rest API: [Runs - Run Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) , the other uses object type [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) to loop all instances and set the job numbers.

Refer to the following steps:

For the pipeline to get the number of the instances, you can get all instances names and pass them to another pipeline:

For example:

```
$token = "PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{orgname}/{projectname}/_apis/pipelines/{PipelineID}/runs?api-version=5.1-preview"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$JSON = @'
{
  


  "resources": {
    "repositories": {
      "self": {
        "refName": "refs/heads/master"
      }
    }
  },
  "templateParameters": {
    "instances":"[instance1,instance2,instance3]"
   },



}
'@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json
```

For the pipeline to set the jobs, you can define the object parameters and loop all values.

For example:

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-20.04

parameters:
  - name: instances
    type: object
    default: []

jobs:
- ${{ each instance in parameters.instances }}: 
  - job: 
    steps:
      - script: echo ${{ instance }}
```

Result:

When we pass 3 instances to the pipeline, it will create 3 jobs.

[image]

You can also refer to [my another ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65297904/pass-parameters-to-devops-build-pipeline-from-api/65301086#65301086).

Answer (score 1):

May be matrix jobs is the correct solution.
You just need to build simple JSON in your data collection task.

```
{
  "entity1": {
    "Key1": "Value1", 
    "Key2": "Value2"
  },
  "entity2": {
    "Key1": "Value3", 
    "Key2": "Value4"
  }
}
```

Output it as pipeline variable.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax
Create dependency for the following "Matrix" to be the collection task and use the variables in the JSON as parameters for a script.

```
- job: collectionJob
  steps:
    - task: <Propertask>
      name: generator
      # PowerShell example for emitting the var:
      # $json = $collectedData | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
      # Write-Host -Object "##vso[task.setvariable variable=json;isOutput=true]$json"
- job: doThings
  dependsOn: collectionJob
  condition: <check if the json is having content>
  # The json is a string so length() with combination of gt() works
  # gt(length(dependencies.collectionJob.outputs['generator.json']),12)
  strategy: 
    maxParallel: <define how many>
    matrix: $[ dependencies.collectionJob.outputs['generator.json'] ]
  steps:
    # Using PowerShell as example
    - task: PowerShell@2
      name: scriptTask
      displayName: Task Name - 
      inputs:
        pwsh: true
        ScriptType: filePath
        ScriptPath: <path>/script.ps1
        ScriptArguments: >-
          -Key1 $Key1
          -Key2 $Key2
```

Based on the example JSON you will get two jobs with names:

- Task Name - entity1
- Task Name - entity2
  And those two jobs will have their respective variables passed to the script.
  More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-job-strategy?view=azure-pipelines